# how to add custom data in excel file laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Maatwebsite to export data from Laravel to Excel, 
but it only throws a junk of data in it, I want to custom design how I want to insert the data in.

for example I want to add tittle at lane C 4 I want to do something like

```
$column->atAtSpecificRow('C', '4', $title);
```

I don't know if that works or how it can work, so any suggestion?

**UPDATE:** 
I use this to export an array of data

```
$sheet->fromArray($data);
$sheet->setCellValue('D5', 'Test');
```

I want to add data from cell D5 and lower, how can I do that?

Comment: any updates about this question? I need the same thing

Comment: nothing, no help at all

Comment: I got my export part ready, I am working on the import as we speak. If I find a way to create something similar I will update you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean from the **cell D5 and lower**?
You could use a loop to go from D5 and below...

```
for($x=6; $x<30; $x++)
{
   $sheet->setCellValue('D'.$x, 'Row '. $x);
}
```